# What is a word for a 'collection of material or knowledge'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word could replace *collection of material or knowledge* below

> The *collection of material or knowledge* on bicycle maintenance is extensive.

Comment: What kind of material? What kind of knowledge? You could be referring to an archive full of paper documents, or an electronic resource, or something more abstract like the sum total of human knowledge.

Comment: Colleen. You haven't finished reading the [Tour]. Please do. It will help you learn about this site.

Answer (score 3):

***literature***

> all the information relating to a subject, especially information written by experts:
>
> - There is very little literature on the disease. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/literature))

Answer (score 3):

**Body of knowledge**

> As in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_of_knowledge), a body of knowledge (BOK or BoK) is the complete set of concepts, terms and activities that make up a professional domain, as defined by the relevant learned society or professional association.

Comment: You can also use 'corpus' for this.

Comment: @Brandin, thanks for the suggestion, according to https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corpus , I think 'corpus' may not be an appropriate choice for what is asked in OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Compendium**

> A collection of concise but detailed information about a particular subject, especially in a book or other publication.

This may help prove them point, in that claiming even the "concise but detailed information" is extensive, you're claiming that the full body of knowledge is particularly vast.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/compendium)

Comment: I added the **n** for you.

Comment: Thanks. My life is an ever ending series of typos.

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple! In the example given, the word

[**information**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/information)

will serve as it encompasses both concrete and abstract knowledge. Trying to extend it in any way is unnecessary and unhelpful.

Thus

> The *information* on bicycle maintenance is extensive.

or using a plain English choice and order of words:

> There *is a lot of* information *about* bicycle maintenance.

although, you can go even further and write:

> There is a lot of information about *repairing bicycles*.

However my mother would probably have said:

> You can find a lot about *repairing bicycles*.

Now, there was someone who spoke English!